# Google Wallet Generic Class (two-item row is not shown)

Tags: wallet, google-wallet

I followed the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-android#9) for adding a new card to google wallet (of course I used the business profile of the company and the issuer id was not temporary).

As one of steps, I added one row with two items, in [generic_class.js](https://github.com/google-wallet/android-codelab/blob/main/backend/generic_class.js),but it is not shown in the final generated card

```
'classTemplateInfo': {
'cardTemplateOverride': {
  'cardRowTemplateInfos': [
    {
      'twoItems': {
        'startItem': {
          'firstValue': {
            'fields': [
              {
                'fieldPath': 'object.textModulesData["company"]',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        'endItem': {
          'firstValue': {
            'fields': [
              {
                'fieldPath': 'object.textModulesData["badgeId"]',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

(of course, if I click on details, they are shown in the bottom, outside of the card).

[image]

Then I noticed that the final card of the codelab is also without the row!

[image]

So I want to add two or three rows to my generic_class like the [pass builder](https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/resources/pass-builder), any idea?
[image]

I searched the web and asked wallet support team, no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I found the solution! I wrongly updated the class :-| It should be like this:

```
  updatedClass['classTemplateInfo'] = {
    "cardTemplateOverride": {
      "cardRowTemplateInfos": [
        {
          "twoItems": {
            "startItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['company']"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "endItem": {
              "firstValue": {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "fieldPath": "object.textModulesData['badgeId']"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

};

I had written an extra `'classTemplateInfo': {` under the `updatedClass['classTemplateInfo'] = {` and that's why it didn't work!

[image: the final result of the Card with row!]

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue and would like to ask if you can help me fix it. 
Does it need to call all three methods `CreateClass`,`CreateObject`,`CreateJWTNewObjects` each after one?  I'm using C#

Comment: I got only below code with `createclass` method from codelab:
```C#
   GenericClass newClass = new GenericClass
        {
            Id = $"{issuerId}.{classSuffix}"
}
```

Your small help will make lots my work simpler @Parissa

Comment: when you call CreateClass, it just makes you a new class, that you are able to see that in you Wallet Console, but to add the pass to your wallet, you need either to create object and make jwt later or just call CreateJWTNewObject to make you a new object as well as making a jwt for you and it gives you the whole URL that you need to add the pass to your wallet.

Comment: thanks @Parrisa, my issue fixed now...

Answer (score 1):

The support service helped solve a similar problem. You need to replace 'object.textModulesData["company"]' with "object.textModulesData['company']"

Comment: thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. I think it is an issue related to not recognizing the object, to use their values and show in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while completing the manual [enter link description here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web#6). However, in my case, detailed information was not displayed either. Displaying detailed information was achieved only by default after removing the detailsTemplateOverride field from the class description. It was not possible to achieve correct display of information on the front side.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing a closing curly brace on your class object

Comment: it looks like this because it is part of code, in the whole code it has one more closing curly and the result is the same!